# Uploading a photo using XMLHtttpRequest to a Flask webserver

Tags: python, ajax, http, flask, winjs

I'm creating a WinJS app and using XMLHttpRequest to send a photo as a blob to a Flask webserver.

```
openPicker.pickSingleFileAsync().then(function (file) {
        file.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.read).done(function (stream) {
            var blob = MSApp.createBlobFromRandomAccessStream("application/octet-stream", stream);
            var fdata = new FormData();
            fdata.append("file", blob, "photo.jpg");

            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/addPhoto", true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
            xmlhttp.send(fdata);
        });
    });
```

This results in the following HTTP request:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/addPhoto HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/octet-stream, multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7dd2a320aa0ec0
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.7,ja;q=0.3
UA-CPU: AMD64
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0; MSAppHost/1.0)
Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
Content-Length: 9471100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

-----------------------------7dd2a320aa0ec0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="photo.jpg"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Handling the request on the Flask web server

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/images'
@app.route('/api/addPhoto', methods=['POST'])
def addPhoto():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            f = request.files['file']
            if f and allowed_file(f.filename):
                    return "error" #add error response here
        else:
                    filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
                    f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
                    f.close
                    return "ok" #add success response here
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' object is not callable
```

I have a few questions that I can't find answers for:

- Am I sending the data in the right format? Am I appending data to my form correctly?
- Are my HTTP content types correct?
- Am I trying to pull the file from the HTTP request incorrectly?

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you seeing TypeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' object is not callable?? Can you post the full stacktrace? Luckily this looks like just some Flask / Python error and not some weird HTTP issue, at least to start.

Also if you're not using pdb it may be helpful here... just "import pdb" at the top, and then pdb.set_trace() at the start of your handler and step through to debug.

Comment: Your content type header seems wrong to me, why does it have `application/octet-stream, ` before `multipart/form-data`.

Answer (score 3):

try to replace this:

```
f = request.files('file')
```

with:

```
f = request.files['file']
```

Comment: Ah - I originally had that but then changed it. I changed it back (see above). I get the following error now: raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method).

Comment: then you should please point out which line the stack trace points to.