# Sending cropped image blob with xmlhttprequest to flask server

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask, xmlhttprequest, cropperjs

Form

```
<h2 class="uk-modal-title">Change Profile Picture</h2><br>
    <form action="{{url_for('upload_dp', username=username)}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" placeholder="Upload profile picture" onchange="loadFile(event)" id="uploaded" required>

    <img id="dp">                
    <button onclick="beforeSubmit()">Upload</button>
```

Javascript

```
var cropper;

function loadFile(image) {
    var dp = document.getElementById('dp');
    dp.src = URL.createObjectURL(image.target.files[0]);
    dp.onload = function() { URL.revokeObjectURL(dp.src)};
    cropper = new Cropper(dp, { aspectRatio: 1 });
}

function beforeSubmit() {
    cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toBlob((blob) => {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("dp", blob);
        formData.append('username', '{{username|safe}}');
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
        xhr.open( "POST", "/upload_dp");
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
        xhr.send(formData);
    }, "image/jpeg");
}
```

When an image is uploaded for , it renders and a cropper appears on it. Till here, things work fine.

User, changes cropper according to his need and on pressing button Upload, function beforeSubmit runs where the problem lies. I do not receive any files in the flask application. The request below has non-empty stream and I receive the argument username, but the file dp having cropped image as blob is not received! Please help.

```
print(request.__dict__)
```

Is stream the blob file? How are xmlhttprequest with files seen in flask?

Comment: Remove the setRequestHeader line

Comment: Earlier, I tried to do it without setRequestHeader. It shows just this entry in request.stream.readlines().
    b'-----------------------------91015450816776636451941570066--\r\n'
I don't think it is my cropped image.

Comment: What's your take on this @Musa , why is this happening?

Comment: Check `request.files` for your file

Comment: ImmutableMultiDict([]) . Empty

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003266/uploading-a-photo-using-xmlhtttprequest-to-a-flask-webserver

Comment: do it without setRequestHeader, than parse your data in server side. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST